# Mobile Emulation Selenium Python - Code is unreachable

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chrome-options, mobileemulation

Hey all trust that you're well, I'm currently receiving a **Code is unreachable**, it seems to work when I remove **mobile emulation**, however I need **mobile emulation**

**Code:**

```
def test_instance(data, tgs):

    Options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    mobile_emulation = {"userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.63 Mobile Safari/535.19"}

    Options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)

    Options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
    #Options.add_argument("--headless")
    #Options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
    #Options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
```

**Error:**

```
Code is unreachablePylance
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve exactly?? can you be more specific please

Comment: Hey @ahmedmani I've developed a bot that requires mobile emulation, and it recently started giving me the unreachable error I'm trying to resolve this, I've found that when I remove mobile emulation it seems to work.

Comment: by a mobile emulation do you mean a bot that runs on a android emulator? if so what are you trying to do automate a app or a website?

Comment: @ahmedmani Selenium Instagram bot

Comment: you're simply getting the mobile site back for instagram.com you can use the desktop site there isn't much advantages to using mobile website instead of desktop site